# staement conversion from oracle to mysql on index

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a query in oracle as 
    "**CREATE INDEX  index_i1
   ON test ( nvl(id,0))**;"

if am converting this into mysql 
    "**create index index_i1 on test(ifnull(data,0))**;" am getting syntax error to use near id

What is the proper way to convert this.
Thanks
SKP

Comment: I think you need to add a stored generated column of `ifnull(data, 0)` and index that. http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/ *only a stored Generated Column can be be a part of an index*

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax to create index in mysql

```
 CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
        [index_type]
        ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
        [index_option] 
        [algorithm_option | lock_option] ...

    index_col_name:
        col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]

    index_type:
        USING {BTREE | HASH}

    index_option:
        KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
      | index_type
      | WITH PARSER parser_name
      | COMMENT 'string'

    algorithm_option:
        ALGORITHM [=] {DEFAULT|INPLACE|COPY}

    lock_option:
        LOCK [=] {DEFAULT|NONE|SHARED|EXCLUSIVE}
```

For example:

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

`NAME` is the column name here where you want to add index

[Official site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

This is your statement:

```
create index index_i1 on test(data);
```

I assume test is table name and `data` is the column name. You can set default value of data at the table structure creation time.